# Como hago que el formulario 1 este pendiente de los radiobutton del formulario 2 y que no se reinicie la configuracion de los radiobutton Windows c#

Tags: c#, windows

Me explico, Estoy creando un exploit multi api osea que la persona que use el programa podra elegir que api usar para eso usare el radio button, lo que pasa es que no quiero poner los radio button en el form 1 si no en el form 3 que es el de la configuracion de programa, lo que pasa es que si los pongo ahi cada vez que abro el formulario se resetea la configuracion de los radio button activo uno cambio de form y cuando vuelvo se activa el predeterminado que puse yo, ayuda xfa esta muy complejo incluso creo que no se puede lograr.

Lo siento Aun no he implementado esa funcion asi que no hay codigo , lo que mostrar Solo queria saber una idea de como implementarla Es complicado, lo que quiero es Tener 3 radiobuttons en el Formulario 3 y que un boton en el formulario 1 haga diferentes cosas dependiendo de cual este activo, lo que pasa es que cuando voy al formulario 3 y activo un radiobutton, cuando vuelvo al Formulario 1 no se acuerda de cual elegí y reinicia la configuración de los radiobutton haciendo que cuando pulso el boton del formulario 1 siempre pase lo mismo sin importar cual radiobutton elija ya que se reinicia

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que estas pidiendo no solamente es simple, es basico para cualquier sistema. El problema que tenes es pensar que un form no es un objeto como cualquier otro, y que deberia quedarse como esta. Eso no es cierto, es un objeto y por lo cual, si queres que se guarden los cambios, lo tenes que hacer en algun lugar.

Comment: Abris el form3, GUARDAS LO QUE SELECIONA EL USUARIO, y luego si lo vuelve a abrir, recuperas eso, que igual tenias que guardarlo para usarlo en el form1. Si pensas, que eso que hacen todos los programas (inclusive tu navegador, que guarda las propiedades, no?) no se puede hacer, te recomendaria revisar tus conocimientos y entender como funciona cualquier sistema.

Comment: Igual asi como esta es impposible ayudarte.. no vemos que haces como para decirte que es lo que no esta bien...

Comment: para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Lo siento Aun no he implementado esa funcion asi que no hay codigo , lo que mostrar Solo queria saber una idea de como implementarla Es complicado, lo que quiero es Tener 3 radiobuttons en el Formulario 3 y que un boton en el formulario 1 haga diferentes cosas dependiendo de cual este activo, lo que pasa es que cuando voy al formulario 3 y activo un radiobutton, cuando vuelvo al Formulario 1 no se acuerda de cual elegí y reinicia la configuración de los radiobutton haciendo que cuando pulso el boton del formulario 1 siempre pase lo mismo sin importar cual radiobutton elija ya que se reinicia

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-application-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es entonces guardar el radiobutton seleccionado en los settings de la aplicación (como comenta @Mateo) o en un archivo, y entonces cuando le das al botón, leer esa información y actuar en consecuencia dependiendo de lo que esté informado.